# FlatList limit swipe area

Tags: react-native

I want to use the edges of my flatlist for gestures and only allow scrolling the flatlist when the user touches the inner area of my flatlist.

```
________________

   |content| - other gesture activates here
----------------
   |content| 
   |content| ↑
   |content| scrollable area
   |content| ↓
   |content| 
----------------
   |content| - other gesture activates here
________________
```

How can I do this in my React Native project?

Answer (score -1):

Try using:

- ListHeaderComponent
- ListFooterComponent

These Can be a React Component Class, a render function, or a rendered element. Read more here: https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#listfootercomponent